# In my laptop chrome ois not launching

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, google, helpfile

I have ubuntu 22.04 lts in my machine. Suddenly my chrome is not launching. I tried reinstalling it but it didn't worked.
I am getting following log in my terminal
$ google-chrome
[12718:12718:0216/195005.675469:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195005.701381:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[12718:12718:0216/195006.122918:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195006.503927:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195006.808613:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195007.100358:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195007.393411:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195007.659100:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195007.931105:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195008.306537:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[12718:12718:0216/195008.306572:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
[0216/195008.329542:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)