google-chrome-stable segfaulting after upgrade to 123.0.6312.105
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4. I just ran a full sudo apt upgrade and then rebooted. Among the upgraded packages was google-chrome-stable, which no longer launches. The upgraded version is 123.0.6312.105. When trying to launch google-chrome-stable from command line, I get the error:
[0407/181659.674628:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

If I add the --no-sandbox flag, I get the same error.

You haven't really posted a question. I do have the same problem though after update to 24.04 with Google Chrome 125.0.6422.76.

The same problem is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503759/in-my-laptop-chrome-ois-not-launching

It may have something to do with: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40935904
